# I am big and small?

Tags: riddle

Find the answer :

- My first is in my third
- My second used to walk fast
- My third is you + me

Who am I?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you:

> Uranus?

Starting with the last clue first...

My third is you + me

> You + me = ***us***

My first is in my third

> "**U**" is in "us"

My second used to walk fast

> **Ran**, past tense (used to) of run (walk fast)

Put it all together:

> U ran us

The title: "*I am big and small?*"

> The planet Uranus is obviously very big. It is has the fourth-largest planetary mass in our solar system and is termed an *ice giant*. But as the seventh planet from the sun it is very far away and so appears very small to us.