# First, Second, Third

Tags: riddle

Find the answer :

- My first is also third
- My second is fast
- My third is actually second

Who am I?

Comment: Got the words actually from (but not related to) - https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68601/i-am-big-and-small.

Comment: Are you Unaqf bs n pybpx(Rot13)?

Comment: @ManojKumar that is not a *who*, but perhaps the "unaqf" part might tie in, like how [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/)$[$rirel pybpx unf n snpr$]$, perhaps.

Comment: @ManojKumar Lrf. Cyrnfr nqq vg va nafjref jvgu rkcynangvbaf...

Comment: @user477343 More or less... :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you:

> A **Clock** (credit to @ManojKumar who suggested this in a comment)

Here's my stab at explaining the riddle:

My first is also third

> There are three hands on a clock - the ***hour*** hand, the ***minute*** hand, and the ***second*** hand. If they all began from the same starting point (12:00:00) then the *hour* hand (which is *first* in terms of the order HH:MM:SS are presented) would be the *last* (or *third*) to complete a cycle around the clock face.

My second is fast

> Whether you take this to mean the minute hand which is *second* in order of ranking, or the hand which marks the seconds of time, it travels around the clock face faster than the hour hand.

My third is actually second

> As already explained, I believe this could be a play on the word "second" because the hand that marks the seconds of time is third in order of HH:MM:SS, so the *third* hand *is* the *second hand*.